# vim make only print result when program terminates and is out of order

Tags: vim, makefile

The following code works fine when I use `make` in command line, but if I use vim `:make` command, all text only prints when program terminates and the result is out of order.

The correct output:

```
> test
 test
```

but in vim `:make`, I got

```
> test
```

The code is as follows:

repl.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char input[2048];

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        fputs("> ", stdout);
        fgets(input, 2048, stdin);
        printf("%s", input);
        return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
run: repl
        ./repl
repl: repl.o
        cc -o repl repl.c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim captures the `make` output in order to parse it and display any compilation errors in the *quickfix window*. If you observe the processes during the `:make` run, you'll notice a command-line like

```
/bin/bash -c make  2>&1| tee /tmp/v0YCPH1/16
```

The main use case for `:make` is running non-interactive builds, not doing user interaction. If some sort of testing is your goal, you could add a dedicated `test` target, e.g.:

```
test: repl
        echo "test" | ./repl
```

Alternatively, if you add

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after the `fputs()` call, you'll get the expected output, as this explicitly clears the output buffers before the input.

Comment: If you are running an interactive build and have a new enough Vim. You may want to checkout `:terminal` which will let you open a terminal-like buffer where you can test your build interactively. See `:h terminal`